# How can I automatically select a command window profile?

Tags: command-line, ssh, gnome-terminal

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 with the Gnome shell.

I regularly have a need to access several servers via SSH on my laptop. Sometimes I have several SSH sessions open to different servers, making it extremely likely that I will type on one of them while thinking it is a local terminal window, when I am actually sending the commands to a server.  This can be disastrous of course.
I have several window profiles defined, which change the text and background colors, depending on which server I am logged into. This works well to bring my attention to the particular computer I'm talking to at the moment.  Problem is, I have to remember to set the appropriate profile when I log into a server, and again when I log out.  I'm sure there's a way to do this automatically, by setting an environment variable or something, but I can't come up with what it takes. I know I can change the prompt text and colors, but I'd like to have the whole window colors change based on the server I'm logged into (or not).
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is not possible to automatically change the *profile* of a GNOME Terminal tab, it *is* possible to change its colors, overriding the ones defined in the profile.

You need to use the OSC 4 (palette), 10 (foreground) and 11 (background), or 104, 110, 111 (reset) escape sequences. Examples:

Change the first palette color (usually black by default):

```
printf '\e]4;0;#112233\e\\'
```

Change the default background color:

```
printf '\e]11;#abcdef\e\\'
```

Reset the default background color (i.e. revert to the value specified in the profile settings):

```
printf '\e]111\e\\'
```

The `xtermcontrol` tool is a convenient front-end for these escape codes (and more).

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  I can put these commands into the bash profile on each server and have it change the colors when I log in.  Thanks!
(BTW, I believe you have a typo in the 2nd sentence: OSC should be ESC?)

Comment: OSC (operating system command) is a certain subset of escape sequences. Its semantics is, well, typically something related to the operating system (e.g. changing the window title also comes from this family). The syntax is `ESC` `]` ... `ESC` `backslash`, or (unofficial) `ESC` `]` ... `BEL` -- as opposed to the majority of the escape sequences using the _opening_ bracket and a single letter terminator.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible, afaik, to automatically change the profile of a currently open terminal based on some trigger.

An alternative approach could be that you create different launchers for the different servers, that automatically open a terminal with a specific profile and execute the ssh-command. The launcher thus would present you with a terminal, ready to accept your credentials for that ssh session (of course, you could even set up automatic login).

That could be done by creating copies of the existing `.desktop` launcher for Gnome Terminal, i.e., `/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Terminal.desktop` and changing the `Name=` and `Exec=` lines. The latter should be modified as:

```
Exec=gnome-terminal --profile <name-of-profile> -- ssh myuser@myserver.domain
```

Such launcher will open a new terminal with a custom profile that automatically runs `ssh`. When you exit the ssh shell, the terminal is closed.